# ReportViewer Control- System.Security.SecurityException: That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer

I am using the ReportViewer control on an ASP.NET web page and when deployed to a hosting site I get the following exception:

```
Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the required permission please contact your system administrator or change the application's trust level in the configuration file.

Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers.
```

I realize that this is caused because I am now running in a Medium trust mode as opposed to Full trust when developing.

I am having a hard time finding a solution to allow the ReportViewer control to run in the Medium trust environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find a suitable answer when I had this issue.  In the end I moved to a host that allowed the ReportViewer control (AKA full trust).  This is for local mode reports.... If you are running on a report server then medium trust should work according to:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsreportcontrols/thread/23c37d41-5cb7-4579-86c3-27460e654b65

Sorry about that.  I know it's not what you wanted to hear.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I guess I wont be running reports in local mode from this hosting provider.